# If Captain America is frozen with his shield how come Iron man has it?

Tags: marvel, iron-man, captain-america

1. Iron man props pipe with shield
2. Can be seen in Iron mans workshop

Comment: Can you post photo/screenshot of it?

Comment: If your referring to the movies Iron-man 2, i believe the shield was a prototype made by Tony Stark's dad. Although I would have do a bit of research to confirm this.

Answer (score 16):

As BadMike01 pointed out [Captain America's shield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America%27s_shield#Marvel_Cinematic_Universe) depticted in both Iron Man and Iron Man II is not the shield seen in Captain America: The First Avenger.  It is a prototype made by Howard Stark.

[image]